# Docker, how to remote ssh from command line host to a docker container?

Tags: docker, ip, openssh

I've followed the steps of pipework to container assigned IP address with [pipework DHCP to docker container in here](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#dhcp)

I already getting Correct IP Address accordance with local intranet segment, and I am setting Defaults Gateway to my container with [pipework  defaults gateway to docker container in here](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#setting-a-default-gateway)

And before configuration IP Address in the dockerfile already set

```
RUN sudo apt-get -y install openssh-server
```

But I am cannot remote ssh to the container,why this problem?

please help me to accomplish my tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) would not be enough in your case: [`piperwork`](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) was done before `docker exec` was implemented:

```
docker exec --it <running_container> bash
```

That way, no need to install an openssh server.
No need for ssh. No need for port 22.

You just attach a bash session (shell session) to a running container.

Comment: Sorry sir, still can not ssh "port 22 : No route to host" and your syntax false, not "--it" but "-it"

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto the idea behind docker exec is that you do not need ssh. At all. You attach a bash session to a running container.

Comment: i already start my images to container with bash session $ docker run -it --name=test ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash , on run the docker image,  /bin/bash signifies the bash session ?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto ok, but why do you need ssh then?

Comment: because in my docker is content application web server(Tomcat, Wso2, Axis2, MongoDB, and jms-consumer) i want to remote ssh to docker container with IP Address already add with DHCP(pipework)
And I can also access the web server in my host

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto docker exec is enough for all that.

Comment: But, I cannot connect to my docker, $ ssh user@192.168.23.156 , "port 22 : No route to host", why sir?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto yes you can: `docker exec --it <running_container> bash`: do you have any error message?

Comment: `docker exec --it <running_container> bash` cannot to run syntax docker exec, is true `docker exec -it <running_container> bash` , but there is no error message

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto what version of docker are you using?

Comment: i using docker version 1.9.1 sir

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto do you replace the `<running_container>` by the actual name of a runnong container, right? For example `docker exec -it mycontainer bash` (no `<>`: they are just here to indicate a field that needs to be replaced by its actual value)

Comment: Do I need to add <> sir? i run docker exec with name the docker container `docker exec -it test bash` docker sign in to the container, but i added <> `docker exec -it <test> bash` this are error **bash: erp: No such file or directory** sir

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto no need for <>: it is a convention to mention a parameter which needs to be replaced by an actual value: look at the examples in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#examples: in your case `docker exec -it test bash` (assuming a container 'test' is already running)

Comment: Yes, test container is already running, because if it does not run, can't run `docker exec` **Error response from daemon: Container test is not running**

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Exactly. So does docker exec works, when test is running?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto perfect. don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Iam managed to get in the container, but i can't remote ssh to the my container :(

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto no need to ssh: you are already in a bash session in that container. That replaces the need to a secure shell session.

Comment: How can I access the contents of the container through my host?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto you are running the `docker exec` command from your host!

Comment: Sorry sir, clarified. I've run a container docker exec when I already start `docker exec -it test bash` syntax was successful, and into in the container `root@dbe5a0ee966:/#` When I check the IP is correct as desired, my IP container is '192.168.23.156' but when I remote ssh to my container `$ ssh user@192.168.23.156` from my host, still can not be connected to a container `ssh: connect to host 192.168.23.156 port 22: No route to host` . Needs me, how I can ssh into the container, from the host to the container. but still not succeeded.

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto it cannot connect to your container by ssh because you don't need it: you are already in your container with docker exec. No need for ssh at all.

Comment: Yes sir, thank you very much. Now I understand, I can directly remote ssh without having to open port 22 of my host,

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto that is the idea indeed. It is not exactly the same as a secusre shell (ssh), but the end result is the same: a shell on your container, opened from your host.

Comment: Thanks sir, I have been guided. It's from my host to the container, if from outside the host me (from another computer) but still within 1 tntranet, how?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto then you would need ssh indeed (to open a bash), as you are not on the host running docker daemon.

Comment: How do sir? I've installed the openssh in the docker images.

Comment: sorry sir, if I am less intelligent long explanation of your catch, once again I thank you